# Creating a jsonstring with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a json array and I need the structure of the json data to look like the following example below.  Specifically, I need "success": 1, and "result": [ ] to wrap around the objects in the array only ONCE.  However, my code outputs the json string with {"success":1,"result":[{ objects }} before the start of each array.

here's my code in action. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/vziEecjJWUid2qtcJkp9?p=preview

view your console.log to see where it's looping through the "success": 1, and "result": [ ] at the start of each array.

example of what I need.

```
{  
   "success":1,
   "result":[
      {  
         "id":"01",
         "title":"awesome title",
         "url":"someurl.com",
         "class":"event",
         "start":"8:30 AM",
         "startTime":"8:30 AM",
         "endTime":"5:00 PM",
         "EventDate":"5:00 PM"
      },
      {  
         "id":"01",
         "title":"awesome title",
         "url":"someurl.com",
         "class":"event",
         "start":"8:30 AM",
         "startTime":"8:30 AM",
         "endTime":"5:00 PM",
         "EventDate":"5:00 PM"
      }
 ]
}
```

My current json structure (no good):

```
{"success":1,"result":[{  
         "id":"01",
         "title":"awesome title",
         "url":"someurl.com",
         "class":"event",
         "start":"8:30 AM",
         "startTime":"8:30 AM",
         "endTime":"5:00 PM",
         "EventDate":"5:00 PM"
      }] }

{"success":1,"result":[{  
         "id":"01",
         "title":"awesome title",
         "url":"someurl.com",
         "class":"event",
         "start":"8:30 AM",
         "startTime":"8:30 AM",
         "endTime":"5:00 PM",
         "EventDate":"5:00 PM"
      }] }
```

Comment: you declare your variable arr as object in 

    var arr = {"success":1, result:[myObject ]};

change it to var arr = []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your `arr` below of for loop.

and print final `arr` after for loop scope.

Try like this

```
var arr = {
    "success": 1,
    result: []
};


var entryLenght = result.feed.entries.length;
// console.log("Number of posts: " + entryLenght);
for (var i = 0; i < entryLenght; i++) {
    //console.log("Loop: " + i);
    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
    var myObject = {
        id: "01",
        title: entry.title ,
        url: entry.link,
        class: "event-warning",
        start: "8:30am",
        startTime: "8:30am",
        endTime: "5:30pm"
    };
    //console.log(myObject);

    arr.result.push(myObject); // push your prepared object to arr.result

    var html = '<li>' +
        '<h3>' + entry.title + '</h3>' +
        '<h4>' + entry.categories[0] + '</h4>' +
        '<p>Info: ' + entry.contentSnippet + '</p>' +
        //'<p>' + startTime + ' - '+ endTime + '</p>'+
        '</li>';
    container.append(html);

}
var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(json);
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/c6eHs0rPUiwpb9L3Zyf9?p=preview)

Comment: bingo! I was so close.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify() is your friend in this case. Just use stringify() and you will be doing the standard thing. Assemble your object just as you show it.

If you need specific text formatting other than stringify()'s default (which is to be compact), you can use parameters to stringify() for item-specific replacement functions. I suggest a check of the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify